# GAID/ Client ID Missing in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, privacy, utm

I have a flow of data that sends Google Analytics (GA4) data to BigQuery. I am working on tracking website users and connecting their visits to understand UI of website. When I try to track my own actions, I am unable to see my GAID/ Client ID on BigQuery (where my Google Analytics sends the data). Other GAID/ Client IDs are coming through for different people, but I am unsure why my own data won't go through.

I have tried using different platforms to see if the privacy settings were the cause (Mac/PC, private/public browser, different wifi connections). None of these seemed to make a difference on seeing the GAID/clientID. For the same website, there are GAIDs for other users, but I cannot get my own GAID to appear in BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to see your own GAID, possible reasons could be:-

1. There could be browser extension that blocks cookies or tracking scripts.
2. Check if your GA tracking code is blocking your user agent
3. I have seen in some cases, developers or administrators exclude their own IP addresses from tracking to avoid skewing the data. You can double check on that.
4. Make use of GA4 debugging tools to check if the data is being sent properly when you visit your website
5. Ensure that you are logged into the same Google Account when accessing your website and viewing data in BigQuery. Different Google Accounts may have separate data.
6. When viewing data in BigQuery, it could be subject to sampling if volume is high. Check for that.